# script#, how to diagnose "Check that your C# source compiles and that you are not using an unsupported feature"

Tags: script#

I am getting this message

" Check that your C# source compiles and that you are not using an unsupported feature"

And do not know how to work out what I am doing wrong. Does anybody know?

I understand the general concept of what its saying but I need something more specifc

EDIT: I was not asking to have a specific instance doiagnosed. I was asking if there was a compiler switch that would give more info

Anyway here is the failing code

```
    [ScriptName("Ext")]
    [IgnoreNamespace]
    [Imported()]
    public partial class Ext //: ext.data.Store
    {
        [ScriptName("create")]
        public static object Create(string name, object config)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }    
public sealed class viewport
    {

        public static viewport MakeViewPort()
        {
            return new viewport();
//return (viewport)extwrap.Ext.Create("Ext.container.ViewPort", null);
        }
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public void foo()
        {

            jslate.viewport vp = jslate.viewport.MakeViewPort(); <=== fails here


        }
    }
```

I am trying to get round the fact that extjs4 does not allow

var win = new Ext.Window

instead you do

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window')
```

You can see various attempts at this. All compile but get bounced by S#

Comment: I'd start by making sure that your C# source compiles. If it does, I'd make sure you're not using a feature that's not supported by `Script#`. Seriously? I'd start by remembering that none of us can see your code or your screen from this distance, and you've given no information other than the same error message you gave us. Sorry, but voting to close as "Not a real question" without more details.

Comment: @pm100 I have updated my answer with a general tip that helps me in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is the case where unfortunately the compiler failed, and consequently couldn't report a better error. You'll see similar internal compiler errors for other languages (incl. c#) if you do something that makes it really unhappy. While I totally agree it would be useful to generate better errors wherever possible, there are a few cases where detecting the unsupported construct is as good as doing the work for supporting the construct.

I hope you are able to and using the latest compiler version - things have been continually improving in the error experience from build to build ... for example reporting the c# line #, compiling the rest of the c# code, and emitting an error statement in the resulting javascript for the failing line instead of all or nothing approach, as well as better error reporting in the msbuild path.

In this particular case, I suspect the use of namespace-qualified type names (extwrap.Ext and jslate.viewport) in the code above is behind the error. Actually this limitation was listed in the script# readme (that used to be available earlier, but was removed since a portion of the doc was out-of-date ... sorry about that... need to get something back online or included in the setup.)

Also, as fyi - rethinking some core parts of script# compilation approach to once and for all take care of a bunch of issues. I'd like to get this started, and then publish the sources for the compiler. Getting this fundamental change in place is what is gating next step in bringing the full project on GitHub ... for those tracking the progress there.

Comment: I worked out the problem by using .net reflector pro (which decompiles to fully debuggable source code inside VS) and then doing break on exception thrown. Of ocurse if we had the compiler source it would be much easier to debug, and we could post fixes :-). It was due to namespace qualifiers.

Comment: BTW - I had assumes that ssc read the IL not the source code. Hence some of my earlier questions about 'why cant ssc generated code for referenced assemblies as well'. Interesting to note that JSIL reads the IL; avoids the nasty parsing pass and gets var, lambdas etc for free

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason I see for this error is a partially qualified type name, which as of Script# 0.7.3 is not fully supported. For instance:

```cs
namespace NSA.NSB
{
    class MyType { ... }
}

...

NSB.MyType myObj1 = new NSB.MyType(); // generates the error
NSA.NSB.MyType myObj2 = new NSA.NSB.MyType(); // does not generate the error
```

**Speaking more generally**, I've noticed sometimes detailed error messages don't bubble up all the way to Visual Studio. If you use the command line compiler instead (`ssc.exe`) you can sometimes see a more detailed error message or any thrown exceptions to help debug the cause of the error. One of my larger Script# projects occassionally tosses up the error you're seeing, so I actually keep a `.bat` along side my `.csproj` in order to debug the cause.

My command line script generally looks like this, though you can query `ssc` for all its parameters.

```
@SET SS="c:\program files (x86)\ScriptSharp\v1.0"
%SS%\ssc /debug ^
/D:MYDEFINE ^
/ref:%SS%\Framework\mscorlib.dll ^
/ref:%SS%\Framework\Script.Web.dll ^
/ref:%SS%\Framework\Script.jQuery.dll ^
/out:Output.js ^
.\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs ^
.\RestOfMySourceCode.cs ^
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I've often found Script Sharp will fail silently if there are namespace details in the code.

I haven't paid enough attention to remember which instances gets it upset. But typically these build failures happen when I compare Enums (i.e. if (enum1 == EnumTypes.Something))

Or when you are referencing something with the namespace prefixed. 
i.e.  Foo.Bar bar = Foo.Bar.Create(blah);

I can't remember if that was something that fails exactly - but it is something simular to this

Comment: The best way to avoid these errors is to build the code base often.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine Script# probably prints out the offending line#, doesn't it?  That might give you a clue :)

Here's an example of a similar warning from a Script# Blog:

> http://www.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp-Update-Nov-2009.aspx
>
> The forum at stackoverflow do not allow me to create a new tag
>   scriptsharp, so I am posting here. It seems that retrieving
>   environment variable values is not yet supported. Using
>   System.Gadgets.EnvironmentService.GetEnvironmentVariable to produce
>   "System.Environment.getEnvironmentVariable(..)" in JS gives a
>   compilation error "Check that your C# source compiles and that you are
>   not using an unsupported feature."
>
> Also I see that the implementation just returns null. If not
>   supported, can I somehow embed this JS in the code?
>
> Cheers Bruce

PS:
!!!!SHOW US THE CODE!!!!